# Solving the Euler-Lagrange equation for the brachistochrone problem with friction

Tags: calculus-of-variations

This [Wolfram Alpha Page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html)  contains a derivation of the parametric form of the brachistochrone curve that result from either assuming friction or its absence.

I am asking for help understanding how the solution to the differential equation obtained from applying the Euler-Lagrange equation to the integrand of the the integral representing the total time of descent is obtained. This differential equation can be found on step (30) of the page. I am asking for help in understanding the next step, how setting $\frac{dy}{dx} = \cot(1/2\cdot\theta)$ allows for the equation to be solved, obtaining the parametric equations for $x$ and $y$, shown in steps (32) and (33).

Comment: also asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068293/euler-lagrange-equation-for-the-brachistochrone-problem-with-friction --- it's probably more on-topic there than here.

Comment: the missing steps in the derivation are given on page 8 of [Some remarks on the brachistochrone problem](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265382213_Some_remarks_on_the_brachistochrone_problem)